# How to register message handler prior to ShowDialog() blocking call?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, messaging, message-listener

I'm using a [Messenger class](https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/7237edfe5ebb690d8cc2) in order to send data between view models. There is an `AppView` that hosts two main views in a content control, and up until now have had no issue with sending/receiving data this way.

**Issue:**

Now I added a `ProductView` that shows a separate dialog to the AppView. But when I call `Messenger.Default.Send<ProductModel>(SelectedProduct);`  after calling .ShowDetailDialog() this blocks the `Send` code call, until the dialog is closed.

I tried the other way around, calling the `Send` code first, then opening the dialog. But this means that the message handler in the receiving VM doesn't register in time before the message is sent.

Does anyone know of a solution, to prevent the dialog from blocking the send call? Or alternatively register the ProductVM message handler prior to sending message and showing dialog?

Below is a summary of the related classes:

**CustomerOrdersVM (sending code):**

```
    private void EditOrder(object obj)
    {
        _dialogService.ShowDetailDialog();    
        Messenger.Default.Send<ProductModel>(SelectedProduct);            
    }
```

**ProductVM (receiving code):**

```
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<ProductModel>(this, OnSelectedProductReceived);              
    }
```

**DialogService:**

```
class DialogService : IDialogService
{

    Window productView = null;

    public DialogService()
    {

    }


    public void ShowDetailDialog()
    {
         productView = new ProductView();
        productView.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**AppVM (Main VM's are registered, ProductVM is independent of this VM):**

```
    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        // Add available pages
        PageViewModels.Add(new CustomerDetailsViewModel(customerDataService, countryDataService, dialogService));
        PageViewModels.Add(new CustomerOrdersViewModel(orderDataService, dialogService));
        PageViewModels.Add(new OrderStatisticsViewModel());

        // Set starting page
        CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];  
    }
```

**AppView: (holds the AppVM views):**

```
<Window x:Class="MongoDBApp.Views.ApplicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.ViewModels">


    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerDetailsViewModel}">
            <views:CustomerDetailsView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerOrdersViewModel}">
            <views:CustomerOrdersView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OrderStatisticsViewModel}">
            <views:OrderStatisticsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ApplicationViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".07*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"
                    TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve the problem a few ways:

1. Don't use `ShowDialog()`. Use `Show()`, and make the dialog window TopMost and parented to the main window.
2. Register the `ProductView` in the constructor of the DialogService (do you really need a new `ProductView` each time anyway?)
3. Make the `DialogService` (or a utility class inside of it) register at construction time for the message, and then pass the message on to any displayed `ProductView`s

Personally I like #2- since you are using `ShowDialog`, it implies that only one `ProductView` is ever needed at a time. For example:

```
class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    Window productView = null;
    ProductView _productView;

    public DialogService()
    {
         _productView = new ProductView();
    }

    public void ShowDetailDialog()
    {
        _productView.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay in #2, by register ProductView, do you mean pass it in the ctor like this:  Public DialogService(ProductView view){ this._view = view } Then calling Also could you provide a snippet on #1 solution , making the dialog parented to appView?

Comment: I've given an example of #2 in an edit. For #1, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462682/wpf-set-parent-window

Comment: I implemented #2, registering the ProductView  in the DialogService(). So.. _productView.ShowDialog(); didn't work, but for some reason _productView.Show(); did work. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Because you send the message after you show the product view. Try reversing those calls in addition to implementing #2, and then ShowDialog should work. Remember that ShowDialog blocks, while Show doesn't.

Comment: ok, so what is the difference in using Show(), or ShowDialog() is this case? out of interest.

Comment: ShowDialog blocks the caller until the dialog is closed. Show doesn't.

Comment: I tried implementing .Close() from the dialog service, after I click save in the ProductView. When I step through, the Close() is stepped into, and close is called, but my ProductView doesn't close. Any ideas why that could be? I called close before the message is sent back, so that the handler is registered before the message is sent: https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/17a7e5369a942b8fa2b3